# similar route names in different namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

so in my routes.php i have

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Cp', 'prefix' => 'cp'], function()
{
    Route::get('/shop' , 'ShopController@index')->name('shop_index');
});

 Route::get('/shop' , 'ShopController@index')->name('shop_index');
```

basically 2 similar address 1 for admin area in the Cp namespace and directory and other for clients

so in my admin viwe when i want to link to this page i have

```
<A href="{{route('shop_index')}}"> shop </A>
```

which wouldn't work becuz i have 2 different routes with the same name so i have  to change one of the names to something like `shop_index_cp`

is there anyway to somehow use namespace in there and avoid that ? like

```
<A href="{{route('Cp\shop_index')}}"> shop </A>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**namespace** attribute is used only to tell the **Router** what is the base namespace for the controllers. It doesn't affect route names or the way you can reference them. There is no way to use namespaces to refer to similar routes - only exact name is used so **making names unique is the only way to go**.

Answer (score 0):

You did not understand the purpose of namespace, its doesnot have any effect with route name, and route name must be unique even its defined in separate route group, namespace is there if you seperate the controller in to folder like `CP\ShopController, CP\UserController` etc.. 

in such case you can define a namespace for group as `CP`, so you can directly refer to controller function as `Route::get('/shop' , 'ShopController@index')` instead of referring it as `Route::get('/shop' , 'CP\ShopController@index')`